# JavaFX networking support (TCP, UDP, SSH)?

Tags: java, tcp, ssh, udp, javafx

I've done some quick googling on the topic but couldn't find much information about this. I imagine JavaFX has support for TCP. However, would it be possible to use JavaFX for UDP networking, and would it be possible to use existing Java SSH libraries with JavaFX? I know you can use existing Java code with JavaFX however I'm just not sure if it restricts you from using these protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX is a new client layer for Java SE that can be used as a replacement for Java2D, swing, AWT, etc. All other Java classes can, and should be used from a JavaFX app as you would use them from any Java app. So, to answer your question, simply use the classes in java.io and java.nio